# Including aggregate data in web service response in DDD

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, rest, domain-driven-design, http-response

I've been struggling with this issue for a while. Let's say you have a business application that has a rich domain and in one of the front-end views you show a list of open `Orders`. In this view you show things like that orderDate, customerName, totalAmount,... but the client also wants to see how many items are in the order (basically the count of OrderItems entity). What is the best way to handle this?

**Assumptions**

- The `Order` class has a `List<OrderItem>` which is fetched lazily
- Each ResponseDTO object only contains its core properties and any properties from `@ManyToOne` associations (so `Customer` would be included when fetching an `Order`

**Solution 1**

You can do a rest call for the `Order` resource by calling `/api/orders`, you'll get a response with the core properties and the customer data. For each order you'll have to do a new fetch to `/api/orders/<id>/items`. This is basically an N+1 problem with many HTTP calls.

**Solution 2**

I change my initial assumption and eagerly fetch collections and immediately include the `OrderItems` in the ResponseDTO. The question then becomes, am I going to eagerly fetch each collection of each entity? This seems like a serious performance issue. In this solution the front end would only need to make 1 call.

**Solution 3**

Initial assumptions are in play, so I lazily fetch collections but I move the N+1 problem from the front-end to the back-end (so no extra HTTP calls), not really a solution but at least the expensive HTTP calls are weeded out.

**Solution 4**

In my rich domain model I add an attribute to the `Order` entity called `numberOfItems`. Whenever the method `addOrderItem(OrderItem item)` is invoked on an `Order` object, I increment the `numberOfItems` attribute. It is stored in the database as well. This way I can have all my initial assumptions and use the ResponseDTO with only core properties and I only make 1 HTTP call. The issue I have with this solution is that many people say that you shouldn't store aggregate data like that in the database.

I realize there's no perfect solution and it always depends, but for the life of me I can't seem to find good discussions about this issue. When you google an issue like this you often find information about HATEOAS but that would fit in my Solution 1, which I don't think is really a solution.

If anyone can give an alternative solution or improve on any of the solutions I gave, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should take REST out of the equation - it does not seem to be an essential part of the problem. You might want to use CQRS Read Models or custom DTOs instead of full fledged Entities for presentation.

Comment: @guillaume31 fair enough, REST is maybe not essential to this issue but I am using custom DTOS (the ResponseDTO) instead of full fledged entities. I've changed "REST" in the title to "web service" at least to differentiate between "true REST" and what is commonly called REST

Comment: I'm not talking about the "response" data structure manipulated at the REST level, but about the data structure that gets mapped from the database. You can have a parallel Read circuit that doesn't use Entities at any point, which enables you to compose objects freely with as many calculations/aggregated fields as you need.

Comment: In your example, that would mean `NumberOfItems` goes to a new read-side `OrderReadModel` class but not to the `Order` entity.

Comment: @guillaume31, ok I see what you mean, I think that is probably a solution. It's sort of like creating a database view and querying that instead of the actual table

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with @guilaume31 and recommend to use a custom DTO / CQRS Read Model.

With a specified database query you could get the Orders and the number of OrderItems in only one query. Put that result in a specialised DTO and you're done.

Do not use Entities for this query!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the obvious solution of simply separating your command model from your read model (CQRS) to allow for divergence in terms of structure and fields (which I assume is out of the question), I'd propose either adopting Solution 2 or 4 above.

Although you *say* 2 is a serious performance issue, is it really? How many `OrderItems` are typically included in an `Order`? If the number isn't prohibitively large or each `OrderItem` isn't particularly complex, I wouldn't expect too much impact, in terms of performance, here. Furthermore, it's pretty common in this domain for `Order` to be an Aggregate Root including `OrderItems` so that it can enforce all sorts of possible invariants (like maximum price etc.). If that were to ever be the case, you would need to go this route anyway. Additionally, I can also reasonably imagine other instances where a user would like to see the list of `OrderItems` in an `Order` (that seems pretty fundamental does it not?).

If performance is truly an issue and it is unlikely you will need a list of `OrderItems` for some other feature, Solution 4 is your best bet. There is no reason to store `numberOfItems` as a field in the database though, and doing so violates the fundamental principals of the Entity Relational Model (there would be more than one way to find that information). The correct approach is to simply modify the query you use for `Order` hydration to calculate the `numberOfItems` and provide the count in your Result Set. The `numberOfItems` property needn't be used during persistence.